# Extract rows with maximum values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, extract, dataframe

We can use *.idxmax* to get the maximum value of a dataframe­(df). My problem is that I have a df with several columns (more than 10), one of a column has identifiers of same value. I need to extract the identifiers with the maximum value:

> >df
>
> ```
> id  value
> a   0
> b   1
> b   1
> c   0
> c   2
> c   1
> ```

Now, this is what I'd want:

> >df
>
> ```
> id  value
> a   0
> b   1
> c   2
> ```

I am trying to get it by using `df.groupy(['id'])`, but it is a bit tricky:

`df.groupby(["id"]).ix[df['value'].idxmax()]`

Of course, that doesn't work. I fear that I am not on the right path, so I thought I'd ask you guys! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close! Groupby the id, then use the *value* column; return the max for each group.

```
In [14]: df.groupby('id')['value'].max()
Out[14]: 
id
a     0
b     1
c     2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Op wants to provide these locations back to the frame, just create a transform and assign.

```
In [17]: df['max'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.max())

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
  id  value  max
0  a      0    0
1  b      1    1
2  b      1    1
3  c      0    2
4  c      2    2
5  c      1    2
```